# Append rows to excel in azure blob storage using openxml

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, openxml-sdk

I am generating an excel file in the azure blob using openxml and I want to append rows to the excel file in blob without loading the whole file into memory. The File could be very large so I wanted to get chunks of data from DB and keep appending the data.

I tried using

```
       var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("Connection string");

        // Connect to the blob storage
        var serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Connect to the blob container
        var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("Container name");

        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference(fileName);
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(appendBlob.Uri.ToString(), true))
        {
            WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart;

            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.WorksheetParts.First();
            var worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;

            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();
            Row lastRow = sheetData.Elements<Row>().LastOrDefault();

            if (lastRow != null)
            {
                sheetData.InsertAfter(new Row() { RowIndex = lastRow.RowIndex + 1 }, dataRow);
            }

            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

            // Close the document.
            spreadsheetDocument.Close();

            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            await appendBlob.AppendFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        }
```

SpreadsheetDocument.Open is not able to open the file for appending. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are appending to the existing file .Please see if any of the below is possibly your case for the issue opening a file.

Please check if you have given the correct **file path name** present in `SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file path name,true);`

See if file path name is in  .xlsx  format.

As code is already making use of “**using** (SpreadsheetDocument sp………….){}””, it is **NOT** required to use  `SpreadsheetDocument.close();` statement .You may **remove** that line of statement and try again.

> Sheet closes automatically when the task is completed due to **using** statement.

Otherwise try with SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file path, FileMode.Open,FileMode.Read,Filemode.Write,...)